# Setting the correct database host in environment configuration

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I'm trying out Laravel Sail for the first time and it's been a really bumpy road, likely through no fault of the package. I'm having an issue with either being able to access my test site, or migrate the database.

- **To access the test site, I need my `DB_HOST` set to `mysql`.**

  - However, I cannot run a migration, getting `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided` when trying.
- **To migrate the database, I need my `DB_HOST` set to `127.0.0.1`.**

  - However, I cannot access the site, getting `Connection Refused` even if setting `DB_HOST` to `localhost`.

I'm working off a mid-2012 macbook pro that has seen Valet with all it's brew requirements, various Homestead boxes, and various other tinkering, and while I believe I've turned off any other services running, I can only imagine this has something to do with that?

Comment: do you have DB_CONNECTION=mysql in your .env ??

Comment: @boolfalse yes, I do

Comment: is mysql running?

Comment: @boolfalse it looks odd but it's what is out of the box for laravel sail, and it works, I just can't use `php artisan migrate` without an error.

Comment: @VahidTalebi Yes, it is. Not only do I see it running in Docker, I can connect via SequelAce and the app works or cli works, in either situation (but not together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this sorted and it's a case of RTFM.

`DB_HOST=mysql` is correct, I was not using `sail` to run artisan, and was instead running it against my locally installed php instance. Setting an alias and running `sail artisan migrate:refresh` is working as I would expect, as is the app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running `sail artisan migrate` and the like when running commands, instead of using `php`.

See the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#executing-php-commands)